# MongoDB - Couldn't connect to server..., yes, another error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Apologise for reopen another post with the same problem but I tried all the provided solutions and it didn't work.

My logs says:

```
root@marcproves:/var/log/mongodb# tail -f mongodb.log 
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.272 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.273 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.275 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Apr  1 04:25:29.275 dbexit: really exiting now
```

and my console output:

```
root@marcproves:/var/log/mongodb# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Tue Apr  1 04:55:28.679 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
root@marcproves:/var/log/mongodb#
```

I installed mongo as it says in the mongo official webpage for ubuntu version and this happens!

**FIXED: SPACE ISSUE**

Comment: Sorry, for the silly suggestion, but have you tried to execute: `sudo service mongodb start` ?

Comment: @RobertoSánchez Of course

Comment: Can you show a bit more lines from log file?, It seems that something is making to MongoDB to shutdown automatically

Comment: @RobertoSánchez yep! the problem was about free space, thanks for the help